# Output window VS2010 won't show any messages after builing solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and suddenly the output window won't show any messages after building solution. For example:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: libdnet-stripped, Configuration:
>   Release Win32 ------
>
> 2>------ Build started: Project: tran_cli, Configuration: Release
>   Win32 ------
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

And Error List is empty. How can I fix it?

Comment: It was resolve! Open the Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General, check the "Always show Error List if build finishes with errors" and "Show Output window when build starts".